# Exact argument matches with Minitest mock expectations?

Tags: ruby, mocking, minitest

I'm writing a Minitest unit test and need to check whether the code under test extracts specific hash values from an HTTP response mock. So I set the following expectations:

```
@http_response.expect :[], 3141, [ "X-Pagination-TotalElements" ]
@http_response.expect :[], 32, [ "X-Pagination-TotalPages" ]
```

However it seems that matching is based on case equality, and the second expectation overrides the first.

What is the correct way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However it seems that matching is based on case equality [===]

...which for the String class is the same as `==`.

> the second expectation overrides the first.

It appears that the ordering of the `expect statements` is important with `MiniTest::Mock` objects:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

resp = MiniTest::Mock.new
resp.expect :[], 3141, ["X-Pagination-TotalElements"]
resp.expect :[], 32, ["X-Pagination-TotalPages"]

puts resp["X-Pagination-TotalElements"]
puts resp["X-Pagination-TotalPages"]

--output:--
3141
32
Run options: --seed 29457

# Running:

Finished in 0.001500s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

But this fails:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

resp = MiniTest::Mock.new
resp.expect :[], 3141, ["X-Pagination-TotalElements"]
resp.expect :[], 32, ["X-Pagination-TotalPages"]

puts resp["X-Pagination-TotalPages"]
puts resp["X-Pagination-TotalElements"]
```

> --output:--
>   /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/minitest-5.4.0/lib/minitest/mock.rb:148:in
>   `method_missing': mocked method :[] called with unexpected arguments
>   ["X-Pagination-TotalPages"] (MockExpectationError)    from 1.rb:7:in`
>   '

And *quantity* plays a role as well:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

resp = MiniTest::Mock.new
resp.expect :[], 3141, ["X-Pagination-TotalElements"]

puts resp["X-Pagination-TotalElements"]
puts resp["X-Pagination-TotalElements"]
```

> --output:--
>   3141
>
> /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/minitest-5.4.0/lib/minitest/mock.rb:122:in
>   `method_missing': No more expects available for :[]:
>   ["X-Pagination-TotalElements"] (MockExpectationError)     from 1.rb:7:in`
>   '

As a result, the meaning of:

```
resp.expect :[], 3141, ["X-Pagination-TotalElements"]
resp.expect :[], 32, ["X-Pagination-TotalPages"]
```

..is:

1. I expect that initially calling `resp[]` with the key "X-Pagination-TotalElements" will return 3141.
2. I expect that calling `resp[]` again with the key "X-Pagination-TotalPages" will return 32.
3. I expect that any additional calls or calls not in that order will result in failure.

...

> What is the correct way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Add the expect statements in the order that they will be called in your code.

Comment: Ah. I've been using Mockito (Java) for a while and totally forgot about the "expectation script" model. It looks like that's what Minitest does. Thanks for the clear, comprehensive answer.